# Xamarin Forms Switch text in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

Just like someone else encountered for [windows-phone](/questions/tagged/windows-phone) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171906/xamarin-forms-switch-xaml), I'm looking to change the text next to the `Switch` control in [xamarin-forms](/questions/tagged/xamarin-forms), that only seems to be possible ootb for Android. The difference is that I'm looking to change the control's text in [uwp](/questions/tagged/uwp) (and that over a year has passed since the previous person asked his/her question).

Does anyone have a (relatively easy) solution for this, or is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173611/2124628) still the best solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone have a (relatively easy) solution for this

I checked Xamarin.forms Switch source code, for WinRT platform, the Switch control's style actually follows `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ToggleSwitch`'s style.

So we can create modify the default template based on our requirement.

For the default `ToggleSwitch` styles and templates, please see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299159.aspx)

Please notice this part:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="OffContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="OnContentPresenter"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}"
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
```

If we need to change the text next to switch thumb, we can just avoid setting `Content` property using `TemplateBinding`.

1. Add the default style under Application.Resources node(App.xaml). If you are not familar with this, see [ResourceDictionary and XAML resource references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references)
2. Create two resources, change the value from code behind if you need:

   ```
   <x:String x:Key="MyOffContent">Close</x:String>
   <x:String x:Key="MyOnContent">Open</x:String>
   ```
3. Modify template:

   ```
   <ContentPresenter x:Name="OffContentPresenter"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.RowSpan="3"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Opacity="0"
                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                       Content="{StaticResource MyOffContent}"
                       ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                       AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
       <ContentPresenter x:Name="OnContentPresenter"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.RowSpan="3"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                       Opacity="0"
                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                       Content="{StaticResource MyOnContent}"
                       ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                       AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
   ```

Sample XAML code: http://codepaste.net/qjin7c

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `CodePaste` link has expired. Can you paste the sample xaml in the Answer?